# Proving that a linear map is diagonalizable and finding a similar diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given the linear map $T: \Bbb R_3[X] \to \Bbb R_3[X]$ that is defined as
> $T(ax^2+bx+c)=(a+b+c) \cdot x^2 +(2a+2b+2c) \cdot x +a+b-c$ prove that $T$ is diagonalizable and find a similar diagonal  matrix without calculating the diagonalizable matrix.

I am still very new to this topic so I tried using the basic definitions and way of solving.

First thing was to find Eigenvalues . so we need $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ such that for $0 \not= v \in \Bbb R_3[X]$ we get $T(v)= \lambda \cdot v$ so we need to look for $v=ax^2+bx+c \in \Bbb R_3[X]$ such that

1. $T(ax^2+bx+c)= \lambda \cdot (ax^2+bx+c)$
2. $T(ax^2+bx+c)=(a+b+c) \cdot x^2 +(2a+2b+2c) \cdot x +a+b-c$

so we have 2 equations , we compare and get $(a+b+c) \cdot x^2 +(2a+2b+2c) \cdot x +a+b-c = \lambda \cdot (ax^2+bx+c)$

we now have 3 equations:

1. $a+b+c = \lambda \cdot a$ $\iff$ $a(1-\lambda)+b+c=0$
2. $2(a+b+c)= \lambda \cdot b$ $\iff$ $2a +b\cdot(1-\lambda)-2c=0$
3. $a+b-c= \lambda \cdot c$ $\iff$ $a+b+c(-1-\lambda)=0$

we need the solution to be different than zero so we will first put them in a matrix $ $$\left(\begin{matrix}
1-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2- \lambda & -2 \\
1 & 1 & -1-\lambda \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$ $ $

we will need a singular matrix so if we solve a determinant and get a solution equal to zero it means it has a non trivial solutions
$ $$\left|\begin{matrix}
1-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2- \lambda & -2 \\
1 & 1 & -1-\lambda \\
\end{matrix} \right|
$ $ $ $=-\lambda^3+2\lambda^2+2\lambda$ from here our Eigenvalues are $\lambda_1= 1+\sqrt3$ ,$\lambda_2= 1-\sqrt3$ and $\lambda_3= 0$
we have 3 Eigenvalues and our space dimension is 3 so the linear map is diagonalizable

**Notes:**

1. In the book the final answer is different they got $\lambda_1= 1+\sqrt7$ ,$\lambda_2= 1-\sqrt7$ and $\lambda_3= 0$ but they do not show the way .. what did I do wrong? I solved according to the definitions

2.How can I find the diagonal matrix?

3. $\Bbb R_3[X]$ is the polynomial that are with power less than 3

Thanks for any help and tips  , and sorry if the translations are not correct hope it is understandable!

Comment: You have miscalculated the characteristic polynomial. You should instead have
$$
-\lambda^3 + 2\lambda^2 + \color{red}6 \lambda.
$$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "find a similar diagonal matrix without calculating the diagonalizable matrix." Perhaps you mean to say "find a similar diagonal matrix without calculating the diagonalizing change of basis matrix."

Comment: To build the diagonal matrix, simply put the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ on the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's due to a computational error. Your second equation should be $2a + (2-\lambda)b + 2c = 0.$ (And this yields the correct result, I've checked it.) Otherwise, your reasoning is totally sound! Although, in this stage of linear algebra, you should know that you can do things considerably shorter. Since $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ behaves "basically the same" as $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can "translate" your problem into equivalent one in $\mathbb{R}^3$, solve it, and then "translate back" to give your answer in $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ (you can see $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the space of the coordinates of your vectors in $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ with respect to the standard $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ basis).
2. Without converting your problem into the equivalent $\mathbb{R}^3$ problem, you can't really talk about the diagonal matrix. If you'd do that, you'd find that the diagonal matrix is the matrix with your eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you and Ben Grossmann for the great help 
will this always be the diagonal matrix? if I just apply the eigenvalues?

Comment: If you have different eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ of an $(n\times n)$-matrix  $A$, with algebraic multiplicities $m_1, \ldots, m_k$,[(multiplicity as roots of the characteristic polynomial $\det (A - x I)$, for example $p(X) = (1-X)X^2$ has roots $1$, $0$ with respective multiplicities $1$, $2$)], you have to find $m_i$ linearly independent eigenvectors $p^{(i)}_1, \ldots, p^{(i)}_{m_i}$ corresponding with $\lambda_i$. If this is the case for every $i$, you know $A$ is diagonalisable ...

Comment: You can now make a matrix $P$ by putting all the eigenvectors that you found (notice that you found $m_1 + \ldots + m_k = n$) as the columns of that matrix $P$. Also make a diagonal matrix $J$ with in the $ii$-th diagonal entry the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector you put in the $i$-th column of $P.$ Then you will have $A = P J P^{-1}$.


What happens when you have $n$ different eigenvalues? Do you then still have to check the evectors? Or can you say something about $A$ immediately?